IIS looses SSL certificate binding
We are having a problem in changing the binding in the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager for the SSL certificate, updating it from the old one to the new one.
First of all, here are some details:

We are on a cloud based Microsoft Azure machine, not on a real local machine. We have to treat it as we would for a physical machine, I suppose.
Windows version is "Windows Server 2019 Datacenter"
The SSL certificate has been generated through GoDaddy, has private key and is used with a lot of our customers, but we are having this issue with only one of them, so I'm sure the problem is not in the certificate
This cloud machines (we have one for each customer) are used to send electronic invoces to SDI. I think it's an Italy-only function, as SDI is the italian governament provider that manage the electronic invoces: every company communicate with it to send and receive the invoices. This is not strictly related to the issue, but could be a useful information for someone maybe.

Here is the precise description of the issue:

We have successfully added the new SSL certificate into the "Manage computer certificates" (in the same way we have always done every year with every customer)
In "Internet information services (IIS) Manager" we select the sites we need to bind the certificate to (they are three out of four in the machine)
From the action menu on the right (or right clicking on the site) we select "Edid Bindings" then select the one already existant from last year, then click "edit" button on the right
In the "Edit site binding" windows that pops up we select the new SSL certificate: we can see and select it both from the lookup and the "Select" button that opens the certificates list in another dialog
We confirm with Ok, then close
- At first, everything seems ok: if I reopen the binding configuration, I see the SSL certificate is still there, rightly configured. But waiting some minutes (usually no more than 10 minutes) and opening the binding configuration again... The SSL certificate configured is no more selected!
Certificate did not disappear: if I try to configure the binding again, I can still see it and select it. But then, after some minutes, the binding will loose the configuration again

I have tried searching for this issue on the web, and find out some solutions:

Close the IIS manager immediately after the configuration, then from CMD run the command "IISReset"
Give the SSL certificate a unique friendly name in the MCC
Look for the DSC (Desired State Configuration) configuration if it is ok

First two points have been useless: the issue is still there. Third point, DSC configuration, is quite difficult to me to understand: it seems that it is configured somewhere in the portal azure website for the cloud machine we are using. And one of the hypothesis is that it is still referring to the old certificate so when the Azure routine is run on the machine it looks for it (even if I changed the IIS configuration to the new one) and as it cannot find it anymore it erase the binding. I don't know if this makes any sense to you, and if any one of you knows how to check this.
I don't even know how to check if there is any batch or routine running somewhere that erase this binding and why. I really hope someone can help.
Thank you in advance!

If you are using DSC and don't have hands on to perform basic investigation you will be in the same situation as those with custom web hosting control panels. Using DSC is totally fine. Using DSC and not having a way to perform basic system administration not ok. There are event logs to review and a huge bag of moving parts that are being ignored. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=dsc-1.1

The HTTPS site bindings are maintained in Windows HTTP API, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding So if you observe unexpected changes outside of IIS Manager, then more likely something else on this machine made them behind the scene. The solutions you found are less relevant, as none of them locates the actual culprit and won't guarantee the resolution is permanent.
